# Docker Daemon per user on host

Tags: docker, networking, docker-machine

I have one weird thing to configure is that Can I have docker daemon per user on Host? I want to isolate the process where individual user can have his own docker daemon where the user can run his own services/images/containers and test it. Basically I need this for testing environment where each user shall have his own set of services.

I could see that there is something called docker bridge but I am not sure If I can extend it. Can someone please suggest me somethings.

**Edit 1** : Can I use docker-machine for the same? but I am not finding the way to configure it.

Comment: You're aware that each docker instance requires root access on the host and giving a user direct access to run docker commands effectively gives them root access on the host?

Comment: yes I do and it suffices currently. b.t.w I got an solution and would update it here soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could achieve this with my own Solution. Basically this is easily achievable with custom docker daemon configurations.

This link has all the details. [Dockerd](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option)

And this talks on securing the tcp socket between client and engine [secure docker connection](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#create-a-ca-server-and-client-keys-with-openssl)

However running multiple daemons is still a experimental features since global configurations such as Iptables are part of it. For my case I do not need it hence disabled those.

**Note** : This is adaptable for my use case. If you are with similar scenario and with extra configurations I recommend you to read the Docker Documentation and also a Stackoverflow question if it does not satisfy the thirst.